# Grant create privilage on Role in OracleDBMS

Tags: roles, sql-grant, oracle12c

I want to create a role which has permission only to create table name emp and update emp table.
I found some web pages that says it is not possible.(As i understand)
 Also I try the following code.

```
GRANT CREATE ON emp TO C##HR;
```

But this is not working.It will trigger following message.

```
Do not attempt to grant or revoke EXECUTE privilege on tables.
```

Is there any way to do the above scenario.? Or is it impossible?

NOTE:- I'm using an ORACLED DBMS 12c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

You can grant a user (or a role) the `CREATE TABLE` privilege.  That allows them to create any table they would like in their own schema.  You can't grant a user the ability to create a table but restrict the name of the table they can create.  I suppose if you wanted to get really tricky, you could grant them the `CREATE TABLE` privilege but then create a DDL trigger that prevented them from creating a table that wasn't named `EMP`.  That's possible but it's a poor architecture-- granting privileges with one hand and partially restricting them with another makes it very difficult to understand what privileges a user actually has.

If a user owns a table, that user will always have permission to `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` data from that table as well as running DDL like `TRUNCATE` or `DROP`.  Even if you manage to restrict a user to only being able to create a table named `EMP`, that user will have full control over the table.

Now, you always have the option of wrapping whatever you'd like in a stored procedure owned by a more privileged user (i.e. a DBA) and giving a user (or a role) just the ability to execute that stored procedure.  A DBA user, for example, could create a procedure that accepted a `CREATE TABLE` statement, created the table in a schema other than the one that the caller owns, and then granted the user `UPDATE` privileges on this table.  You could then grant `EXECUTE` privileges on this procedure to your user (or role).  Of course, I'm hard-pressed to understand why you'd want to do such a thing.  But you could.